# What's really happening with new and override under the covers?

Tags: c#, oop, polymorphism

I've found loads of practical examples of this, and understand the practical output when overriding or hiding methods, but I'm looking for some under the covers info on why this is and why C# allows it when according to the rules of polymorphism, this shouldn't be allowed - at least, insofar as my understanding of polymorphism goes (which seems to coincide with the standard definitions found on Wikipedia/Webopedia).

```
Class Base
{
    public virtual void PrintName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("BaseClass");
    }
}

Class FirstDerived : Base
{
    public override void PrintName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("FirstDerived");
    }
}

Class SecondDerived : Base
{
    public new void PrintName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SecondDerived");
    }
}
```

Using the following code:

```
FirstDerived b = new FirstDerived();
BaseClass a = b;
b.PrintName();
a.PrintName();
```

I get:

FirstDerived
FirstDerived

Okay, I get that, makes sense.

```
SecondDerived c = new SecondDerived();
BaseClass a = c;
c.PrintName();
a.PrintName();
```

I get:

```
SecondDerived 
BaseClass
```

Okay, that makes sense, too, instance a can't see c.PrintName() so it's using its own method to print its own name, however I can cast my instance to its true type using:

```
((SecondDerived)a).PrintName();
```

or

```
(a as SecondDerived).PrintName();
```

to get the output I would expect:

```
SecondDerived
```

So what is going on under the covers and what does this mean in terms of polymorphism?  I'm told that this facility "breaks polymorphism" - and I guess according to the definition, it does.  Is that right?  Would an "object oriented" langage like C# really allow you to break one of the core principles of OOP?

Comment: You missed the return type in your declarations.

Comment: bah, SO needs intellisense :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(This answers the "why is it allowed" which I *think* is really the central point of your question. How it works in terms of the IL is less interesting to my mind... let me know if you want me to go into that though. Basically it's just a case of specifying the method to call with a different type token.)

It allows base classes to evolve without breaking derived classes.

Suppose `Base` didn't originally have the `PrintName` method. The only way to get at `SecondDerived.PrintName` would be to have an expression with a static type of `SecondDerived`, and call it on that. You ship your product, everything is fine.

Now fast forward to `Base` introducing a `PrintName` method. This may or may not have the same semantics of `SecondDerived.PrintName` - it's safest to assume that it doesn't.

Any callers of `Base.PrintName` know that they're calling the new method - they couldn't have called it before. Any callers which were previously using `SecondDerived.PrintName` *still* want to use it though - they don't want to suddenly end up calling `Base.PrintName` which could do something entirely different.

The difficulty is *new* callers of `SecondDerived.PrintName`, who may or may not appreciate that this *isn't* an override of `Base.PrintName`. They may be able to notice this from the documentation of course, but it may not be obvious. However, at least we haven't broken *existing* code.

When `SecondDerived` is recompiled though, the authors will be made aware that there's now a `Base.PrintName` class through a warning. They can either stick to their existing non-virtual scheme by adding the `new` modifier, or make it override the `Base.PrintName` method. Until they make that decision, they'll keep getting a warning.

Versioning and compatibility isn't usually mentioned in OO theory in my experience, but C# has been designed to try to avoid compatibility nightmares. It doesn't solve the problem completely, but it does a pretty good job.

Comment: +1 For real world insight into why it is the way it is and the implications of that and how it can be used in the real world.  Great answer.

Comment: As for "breaking polymorphism" then, it's not that it breaks polymorphism per se, it's enhancing polymorphism to make it compatible with real world deployment scenarios?

Comment: It's, um, avoiding polymorphism when you don't actually want polymorphic behaviour :)

Answer (score 4):

I answer "how" it works. Jon has answered the "Why" part.

Calls to `virtual` methods are resolved a bit differently to those of non-`virtual` ones. Basically, a `virtual` method declaration introduces a "virtual method slot" in the base class. The slot will hold a pointer to the actual method definition (and the contents will point to an overridden version in the derived classes and no new slot will be created). When the *compiler* generates code for a virtual method call, it uses the `callvirt` IL instruction, specifying the method slot to call. The *runtime* will dispatch the call to the appropriate method. On the other hand, a non-virtual method is called with a `call` IL instruction, which will be statically resolved to the actual method by the compiler, at compile time (only with the knowledge of the compile-time type of the variable). `new` modifier does nothing in the compiled code. It essentially tells the C# compiler "Dude, shut up! I'm sure I'm doing the right thing" and turns off the compiler warning.

A `new` method (actually, any method without an `override` modifier) will introduce a completely separate chain of methods (new method slot). Note that a `new` method can be `virtual` itself. The compiler will look at the static type of the variable when it wants to resolve the *method chain* and the run time will choose the *actual method* in that specific  chain.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Wikipedia definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming):

> Type polymorphism in object-oriented
>   programming is the ability of one
>   type, A, to appear as and be used like
>   another type, B

Later on the same page:

> Method overriding is where a subclass
>   replaces the implementation of one or
>   more of its parent's methods. Neither
>   method overloading nor method
>   overriding are by themselves
>   implementations of polymorphism.

The fact that SecondDerived does not provide an override for the PrintName does not affect its ability to appear and be used as Base. The new method implementation it provides will not be used anywhere an instance of SecondDerived is treated as an instance of the Base; it will be used only when that instance is explicitly used as an instance of SecondDerived.

Moreover, SecondClass can actually explicitly implement the Base.PrintName in addition to the new hiding implementation, thus providing its own override that will be used when treated as Base. (Though, Base has to be an explicit interface definition or has to derive from one to allow this)

Comment: Actually is at least one wikipedia article in addition to the link you posted: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29, there's also http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/P/polymorphism.html all the online references at one point or another define polymorphism as the ability for a derived class to override behaviour inherited from its parent.  Thus the term "polymorph" meaning "many shapes" - it's the same thing, but different.

Comment: Using new to define a new method that hides an inherited method does not prevent the class from also providing an overwrite implementation of the base method. No breaking of polymorphism by that definition either.